# Comparing generic lists and filter mismatching values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to compare to generic lists, and filter the mismatching values. I'm currently using a foreach loop, but I would like to know if there is a way to solve this using a lambda expression? In the example below i would like a resulting list that only contains the "4".

```
List<string> foo = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
List<string> bar = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

Comment: Could you give some more examples? What if the same numbers exist in both sequences but in different order? Or can we rule that out? Can there be repetitions? Do you want all numbers that are members of exactly one of the two lists?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have a list containing my "old" values. Then i get another list with refreshed values that usually match the old one. But it could either be less or more values in the new list. But I suppose the `Except` method will suffice? Please let me know if you want me to elaborate my problem.

Comment: Maybe you can use `SymmetricExceptWith` on a set such as a `SortedSet<string>`? The `Except` suggestion only works "one way", so if the other set is larger, it won't report it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen But if i create 2 lists and swap places on the lists, it would cover both cases, right?

Comment: Must it be lists? Can the same string be multiple times in a list? Does the order of the elements matter? So could it be `{ "2", "1", "3", }` or `{ "2", "2", "3", }`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The order shouldn't matter, and the same string can't occur more than once. It doesn't have to be lists, but I think they are good enough for this, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Linq `Except<>` extension:

```
var result = bar.Except(foo);
```

Internally this adds all of `foo` into a `Set<>` (internal .Net type analogous to a `HashSet<T>`) and then yields all those items from `bar` which are successfully added.

Note - if you need case-insensitive comparison you can pass a specific `StringComparer`:

```
var result = bar.Except(foo, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The result is an `IEnumerable<string>` and, as with many of the other Linq extension methods, doesn't start doing anything until you iterate with `foreach` or 'realise' the result with a call to `ToArray` or `ToList` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, nice and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Except` twice, consider something like this:

```
var listOld = new SortedSet<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", };
var listNew = new SortedSet<string> { "1", "1½", "2", "4", "5", };
```

Then simply saying

```
listNew.SymmetricExceptWith(listOld);
```

will modify `listNew` so it now contains the "difference elements" between the two original lists.